# xslt transform prints out entire xml file or none of it, rather than transforming it?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml file with xsl stylesheet into html.

this is the java

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("driving.xsl")));
            StreamResult drivingHtml = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("driving.xml")), drivingHtml);
            System.out.println(drivingHtml.getWriter().toString());
```

this is some of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user xmlns="http://notreal.org/ns1" xmlns:poi="http://notreal2.org/ns2">
    <address type="primary">
        <street>1031 Court St.</street>
        <city>Monhegan, NY</city>
    </address>

    <address type="secondary">
        <street> Elm St.</street>
    </address>
```

this is the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>User</title>
            </head>
             <body>
                <p>Detailed Addresses</p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/user/address"/>
             </body>
         </html>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="address">
        <table>
            <th>Primary</th>
            <th>Secondary</th>
            <tr>
                          <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="address" />
                           </td>
                 </tr>
            </table>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when i run that, i get the html from the root template match, but nothing from the template matching address. i've tried other variations of templates, and instead of getting at least the basic html, i just get the entire contents of xml file ouputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your namespace or or modify your XML to something like the following one to add a namespace-prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user xmlns:a="http://notreal.org/ns1" xmlns:poi="http://notreal2.org/ns2">
  <address type="primary">
      <street>1031 Court St.</street>
      <city>Monhegan, NY</city>
  </address>

  <address type="secondary">
      <street> Elm St.</street>
  </address>
</user>
```

Comment: oh that worked! yea! why did declaring the namespace as  xmlns="http://notreal.org/ns1" not work, and as  xmlns:a="http://notreal.org/ns1" suddenly make it work? any links to read about this?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a namespace issue. The `address` element in the source has the namespace  `http://notreal.org/ns1`, but your XSLT doesn't reference that namespace at all.

Try including the `xmlns="http://notreal.org/ns1"` in your xslt.

Comment: i added xmlns="http://notreal.org/ns1" xmlns:poi="http://notreal2.org/ns2" to the <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> tag, same result :(

Comment: ok, i guess this is the right track to pursue, i just remomved the namespace from the xml file and the xsl, and now at least the xsl transform is working. any other idea how to make it work with the namespace though?

Comment: Namespace issues always give me a headache.. you could assign a prefix to the namespace in the xslt, and use that prefix when referring to it. For example `xmlns:ns1="http://notreal.org/ns1"` on your `<xsl:stylesheet>` element, and do `<xsl:template match="ns1:address">`.. to be honest though, I'd have thought adding it as a default namespace should work, so I'm not sure this will either.